# Is there any media/video conversion software that will use the graphics card as well as the CPU?

Tags: windows-7, media-converter

On my Desktop PC I do a lot of media encoding, video editing and converting. The software I currently use, takes up a long processing time as it seems to just use the CPU rather than the GPU for encoding. Is there any software that will use both together to speed up the encoding?

My CPU is a Quad-Core AMD Athlon II X4 630, and my graphics card is an ATI Radeon 7870 (with drivers only, not the bloatware Catalyst Control Panel).

The rest of my desktop is 8GB RAM, 250GB SSD and 2TB HDD, running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: We will need some more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically what features other than [tag:windows] and media encoding do you need?

Comment: Of course that being said I don't know any GPU accelerated programs other than games of the top of my head; so it may not be too broad but still more details would be better.

Answer (score 4):

[Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/) does this. From the homepage:

> Freemake is the only free video converter with integrated CUDA and DXVA technologies for the fastest ever video conversion and less CPU usage. The software automatically detects the optimal conversion parameters and switches on/off CUDA and DXVA for better conversion results.

I have been using this for years now and can safely vouch for it. It has a clean interface and accepts and outputs to a wide variety of formats (over 200).

[image]

[image]

This is it running on my A8-3870K (quad core APU) at the moment, no cuda available. I can rip and convert a dvd to a `.avi` in under 20 minutes using CPU only.

Pros:

- Free
- Extremely fast

Cons:

- Doesn't have a resource limit and can (probably) cap your system if you run batch conversion tasks with scanty resources

Comment: Note that : Since 340.43 NVIDIA driver update, NVCUVENC has been removed which is the old CUDA-based video encoder API. Freemake uses this so will report no CUDA available as in the graphic above which means all encoding will be CPU based. I have 4770-K and now painfully slow compared to using GTX 780 via old drivers. You can revert your drivers but there is a trade off to that re: new gaming.

Comment: Freemake only uses CUDA for encoding so using this on an AMD GPU wont work for anything other than DXVA

Answer (score 1):

Try [Video Converter Pro](http://www.program4pc.com/video-converter-pro.html) I have tested several different video converters and each has an issue, free ones are installing toolbar and are not up to date, but this one is a good one. It has updates every month and supports a large variety of video formats, works perfectly on Windows 7, 8, 8.1 - it comes with a video editing and the conversion process is very fast.

[image]